Large select query but need to re-order the output
I have the following query that now works correctly
 select 
            oc.card_number,
            opt.oper_date as "TRANSACTION_DATE", 
            op.account_number, 
            case
                vf.sttl_currency when '840' then 'USD' end as "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY", 
            case 
                opt.oper_type when 'OPTP0000' then  -vf.sttl_amount
                          else  vf.sttl_amount end as "SOURCE_AMOUNT",
            op.auth_code, 
            opt.mcc, 
            opt.terminal_number as "TERMINAL_ID", 
            vf.pos_terminal_cap, 
            vf.pos_entry_mode, 
            opt.oper_type,
            opt.part_key as "CAPTURE_DATE", 
            opt.oper_amount as "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT",
            opt.oper_currency as "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY",
            opt.merchant_name,
            nvl(cc.visa_country_code,opt.merchant_country) merchant_country,
            opt.clearing_sequence_num, 
            opt.clearing_sequence_count,
            case 
                opt.oper_type when 'OPTP0000' then '05-PURCHASE' 
                            when 'OPTP0020' then '06-CREDIT VOUCHER' 
                            else 'other' end as Transaction_Type
     from 
      opr_operation opt 
       INNER JOIN opr_participant op
       ON op.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN opr_card oc
       ON oc.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN vis_fin_message vf
       ON     opt.id = vf.id
       INNER JOIN  com_country cc ON cc.code= opt.merchant_country 
          AND op.card_id = vf.card_id
      WHERE  opt.clearing_sequence_num > 1
      AND    opt.part_key >= DATE '2024-03-01'
      AND    opt.msg_type IN ('MSGTPAMC', 'MSGTPACC')
      AND    op.participant_type = 'PRTYISS'

OUTPUT:
"CARD_NUMBER"   "TRANSACTION_DATE"  "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT" "AUTH_CODE" "MCC"   "TERMINAL_ID"   "POS_TERMINAL_CAP"  "POS_ENTRY_MODE"    "OPER_TYPE" "CAPTURE_DATE"  "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT"    "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY"  "MERCHANT_NAME" "MERCHANT_COUNTRY"  "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_NUM" "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_COUNT"   "TRANSACTION_TYPE"
"1234567891012345"  25-MAR-24   "004000485011"  "USD"   -2020   "718515"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    "OPTP0000"  27-MAR-24   2020    "060"   "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "05-PURCHASE"

But I'm trying to order the results so that the last column 'Transaction_Type' would be displayed as the second column and 'OPER_TYPE' as the last column as below but I can't find a way to do it.
"CARD_NUMBER"   "TRANSACTION_TYPE"  "TRANSACTION_DATE"  "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT" "AUTH_CODE" "MCC"   "TERMINAL_ID"   "POS_TERMINAL_CAP"  "POS_ENTRY_MODE"    "CAPTURE_DATE"  "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT"    "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY"  "MERCHANT_NAME" "MERCHANT_COUNTRY"  "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_NUM" "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_COUNT" "OPER_TYPE"   
"1234567891012345"  "05-PURCHASE"      25-MAR-24              "004000485011"    "USD"   -2020   "718515"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    27-MAR-24   2020    "060"   "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"

Thanks

Just change the order of the columns in the SELECT clause:
select oc.card_number,
       case opt.oper_type
       when 'OPTP0000' then '05-PURCHASE' 
       when 'OPTP0020' then '06-CREDIT VOUCHER' 
       else 'other' end as Transaction_Type,
       opt.oper_date as "TRANSACTION_DATE", 
       op.account_number, 
       case vf.sttl_currency
       when '840' then 'USD'
       end as "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY", 
       case opt.oper_type
       when 'OPTP0000' then  -vf.sttl_amount
       else  vf.sttl_amount
       end as "SOURCE_AMOUNT",
       op.auth_code, 
       opt.mcc, 
       opt.terminal_number as "TERMINAL_ID", 
       vf.pos_terminal_cap, 
       vf.pos_entry_mode,
       opt.part_key as "CAPTURE_DATE", 
       opt.oper_amount as "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT",
       opt.oper_currency as "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY",
       opt.merchant_name,
       COALESCE(cc.visa_country_code,opt.merchant_country) merchant_country,
       opt.clearing_sequence_num, 
       opt.clearing_sequence_count, 
       opt.oper_type
FROM   opr_operation opt 
       INNER JOIN opr_participant op
       ON op.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN opr_card oc
       ON oc.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN vis_fin_message vf
       ON     opt.id = vf.id
       INNER JOIN  com_country cc
       ON cc.code= opt.merchant_country 
          AND op.card_id = vf.card_id
WHERE  opt.clearing_sequence_num > 1
AND    opt.part_key >= DATE '2024-03-01'
AND    opt.msg_type IN ('MSGTPAMC', 'MSGTPACC')
AND    op.participant_type = 'PRTYISS'


Ah thanks, I didnt think that would work as I had renamed that column. But it has!
